# How to specify which binary Intelij uses when running tests with the JUnit plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I use InteliJ to run JUnit tests.

I would like to specify the name/path of the command it uses to execute them.  Specifically, rather than the specified JDKs/bin/java, I'd like to use a custom command (e.g. my_java).

My particular reason is that I'd like my_java to be a small script that launches "java" at a lower priority. If there is an alternate approach, that would be just as useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to JetBrains and asked them directly.  According to them, specifying a custom binary is "not possible".  They did suggest I look at writing a custom external tool.